# Sending JSON to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm tring to send a `JSON` to a `PHP` page via `jQuery`, but it doesn't work properly:

```
json_data = {};
json_data.my_list = new Array ();

$('#table_selected tr').each (function (i) {
    json_data.my_list.push ({id:$(this).attr("id")});
});

$.post ("my_page.php", json_data, function (response) {
    if (response) alert("success");
    else alert("error");
});

<?php
// this is my_page.php
$json = json_decode (stripslashes ($_REQUEST['my_list']), true);
echo var_dump($json);

?>
```

This returns `NULL` to my `callback`, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a **string** representation of JavaScript objects. You're sending something that looks like this:

```
{my_list: [{id: 'foo'}, {id: 'bar'}, {id: 'baz'}]}
```

**Which is not JSON.** *This* is JSON:

```
'{"my_list": [{"id": "foo"}, {"id": "bar"}, {"id": "baz"}]}'
```

I would recommend using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery/912247#912247)). This can be facilitated using [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the echo before var_dump

Answer (score 1):

`json_data` is a literal with an array inside that you put as parameter to the post, and will be sent as encoded array in the post request to the server.

In `my_page.php` you may want to look at `$_POST` array.

UPDATE: Ehm, I re-read your question and I'm not completely sure of what I wrote. What I said applies to GET request, and I believe also to post requests.